# Ruby send SOAP request with SOQL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, soap, soql, httparty

I want  to do the following soap request

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_asynch.meta/api_asynch/asynch_api_using_bulk_query.htm.

```
POST baseURI/job/750x00000000014/batch
X-SFDC-Session: 4f1a00D30000000K7zB!ARUAQDqAHcM...
Content-Type: [either text/csv or application/xml depending on job]

[plain text SOQL statement]
```

I am using httparty gem

what  I did

```
HTTParty.post(url, :body => "with plain soql statement", :headers => {...})
```

also

```
HTTParty.post(url, :query => {:q => "with plain soql statement"}, :headers => {...})
```

but got error

```
sponse:0x5afb388 parsed_response={"error"=>{"exceptionCode"=>"InvalidBatch", "exceptionMessage"=>"Records not processed"}
```

and

```
 #<HTTParty::Response:0x65b7b08 parsed_response={"error"=>{"exceptionCode"=>"ClientInputError", "exceptionMessage"=>"Unable to find any data to create batch"}}
```

Please advice me